# Change data procedure with cursor current of

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, cursor, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to make a procedure in SQL Developer that can move data from one column to another. These columns are in different tables so i don't know how to write the code.

I'm suppose to be using a Cursor to transfer the data from one column then inset in to he other column using the current of statement, though i don't know how to do it and could use some help. 
I don't even know how you can do this. 
Table 1 are build with customernumber, first namn, last namne and password
table 2 is just customernumber and password.
i need to transfer password from table 2 to table 1

```
Cursor c_newpass is
select */passwd/cnumbr/cnmbr,passwd -- dont know what to select here --
from customersecurity
for update of --passwd, which is in a column in another table called customer--
```

what do i type ^here^ then?

after this you begin the procedure and i don't have any idea what to write next, something about
`update passwd
 from customer 
 where current of c_newpass`

i really have no idea, but i know the examples i have written doesn't work. But i suppose a loop could be used to update each row, because i assume you can not update an entire column at the same time. 
I'd appreciate if someone could write the entire procedure, at least an example so i know what to do.
Thanks for any kinds of help!

Comment: SQL is just the query language - we should know what **concrete database** (and which version thereof) you're using - MySQL? Postgres? IBM DB2? Oracle? SQL Server? Interbase? Something else entirely? They all use SQL - yet many features are highly vendor-specific. Please update your tags accordingly!

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**
Since you're using Oracle, the accepted answer on this **[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070410/oracle-locking-with-select-for-update-of)** may help clear things up for you...

When you create your cursor, you'll join between the two tables you have and specify the for update of (column you want to update).  From there, the `WHERE CURRENT OF c_newpass` just refers to the latest row processed by the FETCH statement associated with c_newpass.

This is just a rough idea of how I think it would work.

```
Cursor c_newpass IS 
select customersecurity.password, customersecurity.cnumbr, table1.cnumbr, table1.password
from customersecurity, table1
for update of table1.password
```

You should then be able to loop through c_newpass, fetching the next row and update table1

```
Update table1
Set password = password
WHERE CURRENT OF c_newpass
```

**SQL SERVER example:**
It may not be what you need, but it can show you how cursors work and how they can accomplish what you need.  I've got 2 tables, and I need to transfer/copy the names in Foo to the names in Bar because the Bar table has NULL names to start out with.  I create 2 variables, one for ID and one for name which will be used to hold the contents of where the cursor (someCursor) currently is.  Once you have the cursor set, you need to get items from it which is the `FETCH NEXT` statement and using the `INTO` to set the variables for `@ID` and `@Name`.  I start a while loop by checking `@@Fetch_Status` to make sure that the previous statement was successful. If so, I use the variable that were just set to update the Bar table, matching the IDs and updating the Name column with the contents of @Name.  Once that is done I get the next item in the cursor using `FETCH NEXT` again. Assuming that there is another item in the cursor, and it was successful, it will do it all over again.

I think you're using a different DBMS than SQL Server, but the concept should be similar.  You'll create the cursor based off the customersecurity table, selecting the ID and Password, and then update the new table based off those columns.

```
Create Table Foo(
ID int identity primary key,
Name varchar(20)
)

Create Table Bar(
ID int identity primary key,
Name varchar(20)
)

Insert Into Foo Values('ABC')
Insert Into Foo Values('XYZ')
Insert Into Foo Values('JMK')

Insert Into Bar Values(NULL)
Insert Into Bar Values(NULL)
Insert Into Bar Values(NULL)

declare @ID int, @name varchar(20)

Declare someCursor CURSOR FOR 
Select ID, Name From Foo order by ID

OPEN someCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM someCursor
INTO @ID, @name

WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
BEGIN
    Update Bar
    Set Name = @Name
    Where ID = @ID

    FETCH NEXT FROM someCursor
    INTO @ID, @name
END

Close someCursor
Deallocate someCursor

select * from Foo
select * from Bar
```

Comment: Thank you for the explination, im using sql developer. I was also suppose to use the "current of" statement for this task. I know how cursors work, but not the current of statement hence the problem.
This is a university thing, and im behind in class a lot because i got sick >.<

Comment: Check my updated answer.  I think what I have might be enough to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you so much! i think i can get the rest done myself now :)