# Oracle deadlock error

Tags: oracle, hibernate, deadlock, database-deadlocks

```
*** 2014-04-29 05:48:49.364
DEADLOCK DETECTED ( ORA-00060 )

[Transaction Deadlock]

The following deadlock is not an ORACLE error. It is a
deadlock due to user error in the design of an application
or from issuing incorrect ad-hoc SQL. The following
information may aid in determining the deadlock:

Deadlock graph:
                       ---------Blocker(s)--------  ---------Waiter(s)---------
Resource Name          process session holds waits  process session holds waits
TX-0006001e-0092c9ce       352    1558     X            413     504           X
TX-000c000c-00529f7e       413     504     X            352    1558           X

session 1558: DID 0001-0160-00064122    session 504: DID 0001-019D-0005CF62 
session 504: DID 0001-019D-0005CF62 session 1558: DID 0001-0160-00064122 

Rows waited on:
  Session 1558: obj - rowid = 00364D23 - AANk0jADXAAABe7AAm
  (dictionary objn - 3558691, file - 215, block - 6075, slot - 38)
  Session 504: obj - rowid = 00364D25 - AANk0lADXAAABkeAEK
  (dictionary objn - 3558693, file - 215, block - 6430, slot - 266)

----- Information for the OTHER waiting sessions -----
Session 504:
  sid: 504 ser: 7765 audsid: 122682168 user: 1699/SWEEPER_RW_USER_0CD40
    flags: (0x41) USR/- flags_idl: (0x1) BSY/-/-/-/-/-
    flags2: (0x40009) -/-/INC
  pid: 413 O/S info: user: oracle, term: UNKNOWN, ospid: 31932
    image: oracle@db-prod.xyz.xyz.com
  client details:
    O/S info: user: myuser, term: unknown, ospid: 1234
    machine: xyz program: JDBC Thin Client
    application name: sweeper_rw, hash value=1328634095
  current SQL:
  update ACT.PERSON_EVENT set PERSONID=:1  where SEQUENCE=:2 

----- End of information for the OTHER waiting sessions -----

Information for THIS session:

----- Current SQL Statement for this session (sql_id=a4nxmk0w7gd6v) -----
select * from ( /* criteria query */ select this_.SEQUENCE as SEQUENCE0_0_, this_1_.CHANGE_TYPE as CHANGE2_0_0_, this_1_.CREATED_UTC as CREATED3_0_0_, this_1_.EFFDT_UTC as EFFDT4_0_0_, this_1_.UPDATED_UTC as UPDATED5_0_0_, this_1_.STATUS as STATUS0_0_, this_.PERSONID as PERSONID1_0_ from ACT.PERSON_EVENT this_ inner join ACT.EVENT this_1_ on this_.SEQUENCE=this_1_.SEQUENCE where this_1_.STATUS=:1  and this_1_.EFFDT_UTC<=:2  and this_1_.CREATED_UTC<=:3  ) where rownum <= :4  for update
```

I have two tables ACT.EVENT (parent) and ACT.PERSON_EVENT (child) modeled using hibernate table per subclass inheritance with one-one relationship.

```
ACT.EVENT
-SEQUENCE (PK)
-STATUS
-CHANGE_TYPE
-CREATED_UTC
-UPDATED_UTC

ACT.PERSON_EVENT
-SEQUENCE (PK, FK)
-PERSONID
```

I have a bunch of threads that pick up STATUS='NEW' events using the above select ... where rownum <= 50 for update clause and then update status='PENDING' and then commit. They then do some work and update STATUS='COMPLETE'. This is so that different threads don't work on the same events. Can someone tell me why this could be happening since different threads should not be able to pick up the same items to work on.

Here are the steps executed in different sessions.

SESSION-A (select 'new' EVENTS and update to 'pending')

```
select
    * 
from
    ( /* criteria query */ select
        this_.SEQUENCE as SEQUENCE0_0_,
        this_1_.CHANGE_TYPE as CHANGE2_0_0_,
        this_1_.CREATED_UTC as CREATED3_0_0_,
        this_1_.EFFDT_UTC as EFFDT4_0_0_,
        this_1_.UPDATED_UTC as UPDATED5_0_0_,
        this_1_.STATUS as STATUS0_0_,
        this_.PERSONID as PERSONID1_0_ 
    from
        ACT.PERSON_EVENT this_ 
    inner join
        ACT.EVENT this_1_ 
            on this_.SEQUENCE=this_1_.SEQUENCE 
    where
        this_1_.STATUS='NEW' 
        and this_1_.EFFDT_UTC<=? 
        and this_1_.CREATED_UTC<=? ) 
where
    rownum <= 50 for update




  update
            ACT.EVENT 
        set
            CHANGE_TYPE=?,
            CREATED_UTC=?,
            EFFDT_UTC=?,
            UPDATED_UTC=?,
            STATUS='PENDING'
        where
            SEQUENCE=?

    COMMIT;
```

SESSION-B (do some work, attach events to a new session and 'complete')

```
  update
            ACT.PERSON_EVENT 
        set
            PERSONID=? 
        where
            SEQUENCE=?

update
        ACT.EVENT 
    set
        CHANGE_TYPE=?,
        CREATED_UTC=?,
        EFFDT_UTC=?,
        UPDATED_UTC=?,
        STATUS=? 
    where
        SEQUENCE=?

COMMIT;
```

thanks,
ash

Comment: Any triggers might conflict with your queries?

Comment: The deadlock trace says it is between these two sessions and the queries being executed in those sessions are by the application so I doubt it is the triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Your FOR UPDATE select locks both tables that are included in the join, while you only update the ACT.EVENT table there - you should only lock the rows from the table you plan to update.

So session A's select should end like (or any column from EVENT table):

```
 rownum <= 50 for update of ACT.EVENT.CHANGE_TYPE
```

As others asked here:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070410/oracle-locking-with-select-for-update-of)